# Webiopi multiple button css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, webiopi

I'm want to change background color of buttons with different color but it end up with overlap css in button and .bd

Javascript:

```
var restart = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro", "restart", "myMacroWithoutArgs1");
            $("#restart").append(restart);
            var shutdown = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro", "shutdown", "myMacroWithoutArgs2");
            $("#shutdown").append(shutdown);
            var schedule_set = webiopi().createMacroButton("debug", "debug");
            $("#debug").append(schedule_set);
            var back = webiopi().createMacroButton("back", "หน้าหลัก");
            $("#back").append(back);
```

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
             button {
                    display: block;
                    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                    width: 160px;
                    height: 45px;
                    font-size: 24pt;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: white;
            }
            .bd{
            display: block;
                    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
                    width: 160px;
            height: 45px;
            font-size: 24pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            box-shadow: 3px 4px 0px 0px #1564ad;
            background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff), color-stop(1, #378de5));
            background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
            background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
            background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
            background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
            background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
            background-color:#666666;
            }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="debug"
onClick="self.location='debug.html'">
</div>
<div id="restart"></div>
<div class="bd" id="shutdown"></div>
<div id="back"
onClick="self.location='index.html'">
</div>
```

Hope anyone can tell me how to properly fixed this issue?
Thank you

Comment: what I know about css, latest loaded css overrides the previous loaded.

Comment: yeah it supposed to be but I'm don't know why this case it didn't overrides. Did i miss something in html?

Comment: have you tried adding new class to html and applying style to it? e.g. myClass and then .myClass .button style?

Comment: yes i'm try it but it still have old style overlap new one. not sure it got something to do with button which create at webiopi function() in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look this post which has the code you are looking for http://www.coderewind.com/2015/10/build-a-raspberry-pi-wifi-rc-car/
I have stacked controls on a div.